# How do I form the gstring below ?

Tags: groovy

I am getting an error on forming the gstring below, can someone suggest the right way to form this gstring?

```
for(File fileToUnarchive: filesToUnarchive)
    {
       antBuilder.mkdir(dir:"${destinationDirectory}/${getSequenceNumber(${fileToUnarchive.name})}")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to double template the last section

Instead of

```
   antBuilder.mkdir(dir:"${destinationDirectory}/${getSequenceNumber(${fileToUnarchive.name})}")
```

just do

```
   antBuilder.mkdir(dir:"${destinationDirectory}/${getSequenceNumber( fileToUnarchive.name )}")
```